# Is it illegal to deface graffiti in England?

Tags: england-and-wales, criminal-damage

From this site - http://www.environmentlaw.org.uk/rte.asp?id=49:

> In England and Wales, graffiti is considered an act of criminal damage
> under the Criminal Damage Act 1971 and offenders can be punished with
> an unlimited fine.

Is it illegal to deface graffiti? For example, spray painting over existing graffiti on a public wall.

By defacing I mean black-boxing, drawing a line through, painting over with the colour of the wall. So not tagging, but just spoiling or covering.

Comment: IMO it could be seen not as "defacing a graffiti" but as a new, different offence of painting a graffiti; IOW that there was a graffiti under the new graffiti would not make much of a difference.

Comment: By "spraying over it", do you mean adding your own tag on top of it, black-boxing it, or spraying it the colour of the wall?

Comment: @Studoku black boxing/line through/colour of the wall. Not tagging just spoiling.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean by persons other than with explicit authority to paint the wall?

Comment: @Moo That's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends...

The statutory defence relevant to the OP may be found at s.5(2)(a) of the Criminal Damage Act 1971
https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/48/section/5?timeline=false

> if at the time of the act or acts alleged to constitute the offence he
> believed that the person or persons whom he believed to be entitled to
> consent to the destruction of or damage to the property in question
> had so consented, or would have so consented to it if he or they had
> known of the destruction or damage and its circumstances...

So the burden of proof is on the over-painter to establish that they believed they had consent to commit further criminal damage (by over-painting black boxes etc).

Comment: So it's criminal damage to paint over existing criminal damage?

Comment: Yep, unless the over-painter can establish they believed they had consent. As @SJuan76 commented, the black boxes etc are further criminal damage unless proved otherwise. Whether the police or local authority would take action is a different matter

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

### Is it your wall?

If it is you can put whatever you like on it (subject to planning permission) - you can paint it a single colour, create an artwork or sign your name over and over. It’s only illegal graffiti if it’s done without the owner’s permission.

Comment: On a public wall, such that the person who had done the graffiti would have been arrested/fined if caught in the act..

Comment: @user35476 someone owns every wall.

Comment: Huh? I meant not my wall. To be clearer, let's say a wall alongside a canal.

Comment: @user35476 oh, you mean the one owned by the canal owner? They can paint what they like on it, you can’t.

Comment: There are plenty of walls that are owned by the state.

Comment: @Studoku the state is someone

Comment: @DaleM Until you try to contact them to ask permission to respray the wall.

Comment: State owned = Public owned