# Is it legal to remove chalk drawings on public property?

Tags: united-states, freedom-of-speech, vandalism

### Politically neutral version

Political group A chalked messages on public property. (Assume this is legal.) Group B, who disagree with A, deface A's message by rinsing it with water (making it unreadable but not removing the chalk) or covering parts of it with more chalk to change the message into one promoting B's cause. Are B's actions legal?

### Original version

[This post](https://studentsforlife.org/2022/10/25/the-losers-of-national-pro-life-chalk-day-the-abortion-lobby/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=the-losers-of-national-pro-life-chalk-day-the-abortion-lobby) shows sidewalk chalk drawings by pro-life activists, which were then removed or modified by pro-choice activists. Was removing the chalk illegal?

Even if it was not true in these particular cases, assume the original chalking was legal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The second and third cannot reasonably be considered "cleaning up." If the pro-life chalking was vandalism, these changes are further vandalism, certainly not clean-up. The others aren't really clean-up either; making graffiti unreadable doesn't remove it.

Comment: I'm not clicking on at anti-abortion website. Can you explain exactly what was done and what the circumstances were: (1) were the original chalk marks there illegally or with permission (2) what exactly did the pro-choice activists do: did they erase the chalk by rubbing, did they use chemicals, did they apply more chalk, paint, or other marks? (Putting chalk on the sidewalk/pavement is technically illegal in many places, but unlikely to be prosecuted. Cleaning the sidewalk is not generally illegal.)

Comment: Related :[Is it illegal to deface graffiti in England?](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/58502/35069)

Comment: @StuartF I don't know if the pro-life groups had permission, but it would likely be constitutionally protected free speech. The pro-choice activists apparently mostly used water. They didn't really clean the sidewalks; they just made the chalk unreadable.

Comment: They also added more chalk to either cover or change the messages in some cases.

Comment: @StuartF I embedded the pictures.

Comment: @Someone Graffiti is unlikely to be constitutionally protected free speech (and technically this is probably graffiti on the city's sidewalks.)

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Graffiti is normally written in paint, not chalk.  Chalk would wash away during the next rainstorm if left unattended and is temporary.  Typical Graffiti requires the offending paint to be painted over.

Comment: @hszmv Chalk most definitely fits the definition of "criminal damage" in England and Wales (which is what graffiti is usually prosecuted as).  Whether chalk marks are illegal will be jurisdiction dependent, but my expectation would be that they usually are.  The difference between needing sand-blasting, hard scrubbing, and just a rinse with a hose is a difference of degree rather than of kind.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica  In the U.S. it is not as it does no damage and is usually gone in days depending on weather.  It's protected speech in the U.S.

Comment: These pictures are from various states, but they're all in the US.

Comment: @hszmv Not always. Courts have found that one cannot chalk the street in front of the White House, for example. So long as the enforcement is content-neutral (no one can chalk the street, regardless of what they're writing), it's not a violation of the First Amendment. https://www.courthousenews.com/d-c-can-forbid-chalk-outside-white-house/. Vandalism or defacement need not be permanent to classify as such.

Comment: I edited to assume the original chalking was legal (I wasn't involved in any of these cases, so an answer directly relevant to them isn't needed), and added a politically neutral summary at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the underlying premise is that public spaces are open fora for any form of political expression, which is protected by the First Amendment.

Under the First Amendment, you have the right to express your viewpoint in a public forum. The government can reasonably restrict such expressions to some extent, thus violent riots can be prohibited, and permanent vandalism with spray paint can be banned. Chalk can even be banned. Any bans must, however, be viewpoint-neutral.

Government protection of public expressions must also be viewpoint-neutral, therefore the police cannot elect to de-police just one side of an issue (based on viewpoint, as opposed to different conduct of participants). Therefore they must protect protesters coming from one side of an issue from vigilantes from the other side, or protect neither side – the government cannot favor a particular viewpoint in law enforcement.

Chalk is a commonly used expressive medium, and municipalities have massive discretion to ignore it and wait for the next rain to clean it up, or else they may actively intervene to stop and remove such expressions – in a viewpoint neutral fashion. Furthermore, a municipality may rightfully tolerate voluntary civilian clean-up in the aftermath of a political outburst.

The (remote) possibility exists that the municipality is not viewpoint-neutral in protecting public expressions – preventing vigilante cleanups by one side while encouraging vigilante cleanups by the other side, and that would violate the First Amendment. The First Amendment does not require individuals to be viewpoint-neutral, only governments.

You might imagine that the drawer could file a lawsuit for damages. A possible scenario would be if the municipality set up a controlled and protected space for artistic expressions, somebody – with permission to create the work – labors over an elaborate display, and a vandal trashes it. The vandal could be sued. The difference between that and the above scenario is that you have warring ideologies, one involving the application of chalk without permission and the other involving the removal of chalk without permission. The government will not favor just one viewpoint by awarding damages for an unsanctioned expressive action, over another unsanctioned expressive action.